# Use kml file with Here ios SDK

Tags: ios, navigation, kml, voice

I want to implement voice navigation in my app and I am using kml file to show different routs. I found HERE mobile SDK which provides voice navigation, but I am not able to find anything that will lead me to parse kml with here sdk.

If there is any other lib which provide support kml parsing and voice navigation that will be also fine.
thanks